# MvcMailer.dll is missing in installing nuGet Package in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, email, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget-package, mvcmailer

I'm trying to use MvcMailer in Mvc 4 using Razor
 I've followed follwing tutorial.

> http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/sending-emails-using-mvcmailer

but, after installing nuGet package, MvcMailer.dll file is missing every time, and because of it, directives are missing and showing errors.
Any one have idea ??

Comment: Any one having idea ? or tell some other way to send a contact form values to email in MVC 4 Razor. I have one HTML Contact page and i want to send email on submitting that form.

Comment: ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with MVC 4, so i installed that version of Mvcmailer and works fine.

```
install-package MvcMailer -version 4.0
```